# install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru error

Tags: go

I have a issue of go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru

When update my go tools in vscode IDE.But golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru package always shows the following install error

error:

## golang.org/x/tools/go/internal/gcimporter

src/golang.org/x/tools/go/internal/gcimporter/bexport.go:212: obj.IsAlias undefined (type *types.TypeName has no field or method IsAlias)

go version is 1.8.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to have to upgrade go. The language added a concept called aliases. The reflection package therefore has to know about them and apparently guru. You should try and stay up to date, as the Go team only supports the last two versions.

As of today, 1.11.4 is the latest: https://golang.org/dl/